# What do you do when you try to sudo and root's PATH has gone kerblooey?

Tags: debian, sudo, path, dpkg

I've got a feeling something bad just happened to this machine.

```
faheem@bulldog:/usr/local/src/mercurial$ sudo dpkg -i 
mercurial_3.0-1_amd64.deb mercurial-common_3.0-1_all.deb    
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable 
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable 
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable 
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin
and /sbin
```

This is an old unmaintained machine I've been using for a while. 
Assuming it was going to die some day. Looks like this might be the day.
It starting throwing errors a bit earlier, and it looks like someone just 
rebooted it.

UPDATE: After running

```
sudo -s
```

I checked the value of path

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

So some stuff is missing from here, e.g. `sbin`, and `/usr/sbin`.

UPDATE 2:

As it turns out, person or persons unknown deleted the following lines
from `/etc/sudoers`.

```
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Thanks to Anthony for explaining.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the 'Note:' at the bottom of your `sudo dpkg -i` output hints at, this is usually caused by `$PATH` being set wrong. One way that happens is when you run `dpkg -i` without root; but that isn't the case here.

An easy way to confirm the path is to run `sudo -s`, which tells sudo to run a shell instead of some other program. So you'll be landed at a root shell prompt. If you `echo "$PATH"`, you'll likely find `/sbin` and/or `/usr/sbin` missing.

sudo's default behavior is to keep your user's `$PATH` variable intact. That default is normally changed by Debian's default `/etc/sudoers`, which contains:

```
Defaults        env_reset
⋮
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

If you're missing the `secure_path` line, that'd explain the problem.

Two options are to add that line back (but someone may have removed it because he/she wanted the user path to be carried over, e.g., because it contains extra elements in `/opt`, for example) or to add `/sbin:/usr/sbin` to your user's `$PATH`.